# What should be added to UPDATE query

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to give the user a permission to change the user type either to become an admin or to a basic user, this is the code that i used:

**First page:**

```
echo "<p>please type the employee ID</p><input type='number' name='id'>";
echo "<p> Change to: </p><select name='usertype'>
      <option>Admin</option>
      <option>Basic User</option>
      </select>";
```

after hitting submit it goes to this page:

```
$usertype= $_POST['usertype'];
$empID= $_POST['id'];
$sql="UPDATE `sap` SET `UserType`='$usertype' WHERE `ID`='$empID'";
```

but when I check the database nothing has been updated, can anyone tell me what am I missing please

Comment: Any error you are getting?did you executed the query or not (i din't see execution code )?

Comment: You're not executing the query. You've just build a string. Also note that the way you've build the SQL string to execute will lead you to SQL injection problems.

Comment: you need to execute the query

Comment: this code doesn't execute the query you have to had stuff to do that

Comment: let me know that write in php file print_r($_POST); die; and show what you are getting in the response

Comment: have you made connection with the database ?

Comment: For your help:- https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: you just assigning string to $sql variable . you should execute it

Comment: Think logically. Why would assigning a string to a variable update your database?

Comment: learn debugging: like,

`if($sql) {
    echo "Data Updated";
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never execute your query you need to execute the query with `query()` or `mysqli_query();`

Then your code should be

```
<?php

$usertype= $_POST['usertype'];
$empID= $_POST['id'];

$sql="UPDATE `sap` SET `UserType`='$usertype' WHERE `ID`='$empID'";

$run = $conn->query($sql);

if($run){

    echo "data updated";
}else{

    echo "error". $conn->error;
}

?>
```

or

```
<?php

$usertype= $_POST['usertype'];
$empID= $_POST['id'];

$sql="UPDATE `sap` SET `UserType`='$usertype' WHERE `ID`='$empID'";

$run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if($run){

    echo "data updated";
}else{

    echo "error ".mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>
```

where `$conn` is your connection string

or better use prepared statements :

```
<?php
$usertype= $_POST['usertype'];
$empID= $_POST['id'];

$sql="UPDATE `sap` SET `UserType`= ?  WHERE `ID`= ? ";
$run = $conn->prepare($sql);
$run->bindParam("si",$usertype,$empID)

if($run->execute()){

    echo "data updated";
}else{

    echo "error". $conn->error;
}
?>
```

or use PDO

```
<?php


    $host = '';
    $db   = '';
    $user = '';
    $pass = '';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
            ];


$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);


$usertype= $_POST['usertype'];
$empID= $_POST['id'];


$sql="UPDATE `sap` SET `UserType`= ?  WHERE `ID`= ? ";

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    if($stmt->execute(array($usertype,$empID))){

        echo "data updated";
    }

?>
```

See [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: I completely forgot to add this, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you have a lot of miss. Because of that, I decided to code complete example, and you can see all your omissions.
Here is working solution:

```
<?php
$usertype= $_POST['usertype'];
$empID= $_POST['id'];
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db8', "root", "");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `table1` SET `UserType`= ? WHERE `ID`= ?");
$stmt->execute([$usertype, $empID]);

echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
echo "<p>please type the employee ID</p><input type='number' name='id'>";
echo "<p> Change to: </p><select name='usertype'>
      <option>Admin</option>
      <option>Basic User</option>
      </select>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit'>";
?>
```

I'm here for every your question.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Explain what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

```
$host='localhost'; 
$username = 'root'; 
$pass = '';// your db password
$database = 'your db name'; // set here your db name.
$connection = new mysqli($host,$username,$pass,$database);// for db connection.

// but db connection is missed here.

 if(isset($_POST['usertype'])){ 
   $usertype= $_POST['usertype'];
   $empID= $_POST['id'];

   $sql ="UPDATE `sap` SET `UserType`='$usertype' WHERE ID ='$empID'"; 
   $result = $connection->query($sql);// it is missed in your code. 

  if($result){
  echo  'record updated successfully';  
  }else{
    echo  ' error------------- ';
  }


}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. *Explain* what you've done.